# Apple reports app crash but I can not figure it out

Tags: ios, appstore-approval, symbolicatecrash, symbolicate

Apple indicates the app crashes at launch on iphone 5, but I can't see where. On my iPhone 5 and iPad it runs perfectly. 
This is the Apple notes and crash report (it's symbolicated on organizer and manually-I think-). 
Please help me to inspect what seems to be the problem.

Apple notes:

> We found that your app crashed upon launch on iPhone 5 running iOS
>   6.1.4, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> This occurred when your app was used:
>
> - On Wi-Fi
> - On cellular network We have attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue. For information on how to symbolicate and
>     read a crash log, please see Tech Note TN2151 Understanding and
>     Analyzing iPhone OS Application Crash Reports.

Crash report:

```
Incident Identifier: E9457CC3-BADB-4169-BAD9-D5AEBC0AC63F
CrashReporter Key:   faf5c17d0c159e839c86919af387d69d056f9fe5
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:         MobileVision [4747]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/C6C4D354-6412-403E-A61A-5077A1B22E9B/MobileVision.app/MobileVision
Identifier:      MobileVision
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-05-13 14:21:39.436 -0700
OS Version:      iOS 6.1.3 (10B329)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x32f8c29e __exceptionPreprocess + 158
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3ae3097a objc_exception_throw + 26
2   UIKit                           0x3512137c +[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:bundle:] + 436
3   UIKit                           0x34f6358e -[UIApplication _loadMainStoryboardFileNamed:bundle:] + 38
4   UIKit                           0x34dec79c -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 524
5   UIKit                           0x34d94c34 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1000
6   UIKit                           0x34d946c8 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 68
7   UIKit                           0x34d94116 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6150
8   GraphicsServices                0x36a8859e _PurpleEventCallback + 586
9   CoreFoundation                  0x32f6167e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 10
10  CoreFoundation                  0x32f60ee4 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 208
11  CoreFoundation                  0x32f5fcb2 __CFRunLoopRun + 642
12  CoreFoundation                  0x32ed2eb8 0x32eca000 + 36536
13  CoreFoundation                  0x32ed2d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
14  UIKit                           0x34deb480 -[UIApplication _run] + 664
15  UIKit                           0x34de82fc 0x34d91000 + 357116
16  MobileVision                    0x0008d642 main (main.m:16)
17  libdyld.dylib                   0x3b267b1c start + 0


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b32e350 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b2a511e pthread_kill + 54
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b2e196e abort + 90
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3a87fd4a abort_message + 70
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3a87cff4 default_terminate() + 20
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3ae30a74 _objc_terminate() + 144
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3a87d078 safe_handler_caller(void (*)()) + 76
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3a87d110 std::terminate() + 16
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3a87e594 __cxa_rethrow + 84
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3ae309cc objc_exception_rethrow + 8
10  CoreFoundation                  0x32ed2f1c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
11  CoreFoundation                  0x32ed2d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
12  UIKit                           0x34deb480 -[UIApplication _run] + 664
13  UIKit                           0x34de82fc UIApplicationMain + 1116
14  MobileVision                    0x0008d642 main (main.m:16)
15  libdyld.dylib                   0x3b267b1c start + 0

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b32ed98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b27ccf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b27ca12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b27c8a0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b31e648 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3b24e974 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 792
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3b24e654 _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$mp + 32

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b32ed98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b27ccf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b27ca12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b27c8a0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b31deb4 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b31e048 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x32f61040 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 124
3   CoreFoundation                  0x32f5fd9e __CFRunLoopRun + 878
4   CoreFoundation                  0x32ed2eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x32ed2d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   WebCore                         0x38ec2500 RunWebThread(void*) + 440
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b28730e _pthread_start + 306
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b2871d4 thread_start + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x3ce24534
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3ce24b88      r6: 0x1c586614      r7: 0x2fd749f4
    r8: 0x1c5865f0    r9: 0x00000300     r10: 0x3520a04b     r11: 0x1d04bd20
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fd749e8      lr: 0x3b2a5123      pc: 0x3b32e350
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
   0x8c000 -    0xb6ffb +MobileVision armv7  <112fdd48bbb43dd491da52d4646fef73> /var/mobile/Applications/C6C4D354-6412-403E-A61A-5077A1B22E9B/MobileVision.app/MobileVision
0x2fe23000 - 0x2fe4375b  dyld armv7  <280610df5ed43ec7aa00629a27009302> /usr/lib/dyld
0x320ad000 - 0x32193fff  AVFoundation armv7  <320761e836883aeabf3cb5c53edb636d> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x32194000 - 0x32194fff  Accelerate armv7  <b68ff92e404931f3bcb6361720f77724> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x32195000 - 0x322d3ff3  vImage armv7  <30522b92940d3dd184c8e46780594048> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x322d4000 - 0x323b7ff7  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <d8edada1cea133458ca779e34a3a7f88> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x323b8000 - 0x3266dfff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <9e08aead79d13043bab622402a270fba> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x3266e000 - 0x326c7ff3  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <09e2a5e3e9203950890ba57592523132> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x326c8000 - 0x326d9fff  libvMisc.dylib armv7  <7b7d4ccc9f2b364cb0da4251e745545d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x326da000 - 0x326dafff  vecLib armv7  <a7751c047dcc35ba8885212e1938b93f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x32958000 - 0x32be0ff7  AudioToolbox armv7  <394ee11cf826367db9ff4968dbc71d6d> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x32be1000 - 0x32ca6ff7  CFNetwork armv7  <4771a5e4f9b83bceb252f0f3d166aaca> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x32ca7000 - 0x32cfdff8  CoreAudio armv7  <5d534dbf76ff30f4a628f25f56c5f26a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x32d11000 - 0x32ec949f  CoreData armv7  <3930f672c76535a2abb768ee59958fa7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x32eca000 - 0x32ffcff1  CoreFoundation armv7  <fcb8d4e838543bcb9a52c9f232b8b4eb> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x32ffd000 - 0x33135fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <81e213f810a034d4ba411f9b505da2a6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x33137000 - 0x33172ff0  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <a5d20b80ab1532d8831027a66d2d9eb5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x33356000 - 0x33371ffb  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <ec1487f9bdb93597a3f8d434406ad9bf> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x33372000 - 0x33427ff2  CoreImage armv7  <6ae4ae2461313e3f84c6a8102d5b1b0e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x33428000 - 0x33480ff7  CoreLocation armv7  <4edb4b0f05e13af8b84699fe3ea4c538> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x334b5000 - 0x3351aff2  CoreMedia armv7  <8592bdc268b83b8886acfc1fdab649ed> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x3351b000 - 0x335a3ff3  CoreMotion armv7  <4512d901170d32e7842e7fc1c519386b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x335a4000 - 0x335faffb  CoreTelephony armv7  <bea09dbe25363c3b8e8016b5b5148055> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x335fb000 - 0x3365dfff  CoreText armv7  <e135debbc8f937299f4986fc3e9459e3> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x3365e000 - 0x3366dfff  CoreVideo armv7  <00f18bb26e663da9ae251a6ec36a19ec> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x337f2000 - 0x339b5ffd  Foundation armv7  <0179934581d13346aa7583165108b95c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x33b70000 - 0x33bb9fff  IOKit armv7  <a98ba9fefc7333e4a5a9169198848c62> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x33bba000 - 0x33d92ffb  ImageIO armv7  <b5ce84bb074d3de4b07b55da9fd8bfd1> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x33fa7000 - 0x34221ff7  MediaToolbox armv7  <ed439fc5c9a03f8b9fae43af33de8a57> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x342a9000 - 0x34302ff7  MobileCoreServices armv7  <77da8a9e7f813f5baf37eaa4a87fae84> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x343f1000 - 0x343f8fff  OpenGLES armv7  <f2ede6b206f336de82cc38619692e762> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x343fa000 - 0x343fafff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <2506af1c983f3f09ac69aca44f67e863> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x343fe000 - 0x34400ffd  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <af6ff28dce6031baaa850ccc79e5699b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x34401000 - 0x34405fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <a6ac1673a088379aa512ba5cac301f5b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x34406000 - 0x34443ff9  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <b8b8f3a1bfd0345e86aa0c2952534949> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x34b3e000 - 0x34c53fff  QuartzCore armv7  <c086b6e6cd9d341399bcc3675c82f1fe> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x34ca2000 - 0x34cd0ffc  Security armv7  <fbc24f15bd9e37539cdd6e3576bde938> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x34d4f000 - 0x34d8efff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <410d69b356e533d6a1d538cf33059634> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x34d91000 - 0x352e5ff3  UIKit armv7  <ad8b3ad23f413187a178179db39cfa6b> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x352e6000 - 0x35324ff3  VideoToolbox armv7  <d2e8067306d9346ab4a448f10f336894> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x355ee000 - 0x355f1ffb  AggregateDictionary armv7  <c2a6c1ff89a9318d8b74fc5dfc8847b8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x35a1d000 - 0x35a58fff  AppSupport armv7  <921794b7d82a3558a0eb860979be199c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x35acb000 - 0x35ad4ffb  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <de7ca29cd47433cd8eca9c04102f5508> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x35b04000 - 0x35b1bfff  BackBoardServices armv7  <772912697ec23e5199a452e97f075dd9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x35b25000 - 0x35b49ff7  Bom armv7  <b5315d733e123a0781683efdc734064b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x35bc9000 - 0x35bd0ffa  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <a4f4b86cc84839f78ff746f013bcee6f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x35bd1000 - 0x35c9bffe  Celestial armv7  <a688df527b65382da586ebc87f28c061> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x35d7f000 - 0x35d84fff  CommonUtilities armv7  <f8fea9ee6ca236b0a7fa6c00eb8a0d24> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x3604a000 - 0x3604bffd  CoreSurface armv7  <6065f7e040e93d6ea2837e929592cc30> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x360b8000 - 0x360bdfff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <03ee46e3ca3f3920a7174e62096723fb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x362e0000 - 0x362e1ffc  DataMigration armv7  <5903e08348b83f119022cbbf83ad100a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x362e4000 - 0x362fdff9  DictionaryServices armv7  <84669055e3e63d6ab56b8fe7b0476aaa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x36305000 - 0x3631dff4  EAP8021X armv7  <6d5ab53850e23fe389e64e2705bd7810> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x36370000 - 0x36783ffd  FaceCoreLight armv7  <43de0b31da3b39e4acf85ec2c8d5c65c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x3697b000 - 0x36987ffe  GenerationalStorage armv7  <d77ad2367fff37d485480aa39df7d325> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x36988000 - 0x36a81fff  GeoServices armv7  <edbf37a31a6a31f49e392ed8ece200c7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x36a82000 - 0x36a8dfff  GraphicsServices armv7  <d4b7fd6509753bff9525fef374ddc359> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x36d79000 - 0x36dc5fff  IMFoundation armv7  <797535fc363c3f818bcd1424251393bf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x36dcc000 - 0x36dcdffc  IOAccelerator armv7  <9655464326203d258d3d0fc7e94651e2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/IOAccelerator
0x36dce000 - 0x36dd3ffa  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <f38c374982a931d5a47458dd3c34ac59> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x36dd4000 - 0x36dd8ffd  IOSurface armv7  <a55bf03c35de3fd9b56dce82083c3d10> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x36e22000 - 0x36fc8ffa  JavaScriptCore armv7  <a5780997f4b738659172f40877c9a7d9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x37094000 - 0x370ecffd  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <44bbb2ba85c8320bb9e73c654b90f8c0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x37103000 - 0x37179fff  MediaControlSender armv7  <9fb205b64b5333a495ac61c149e0304b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControlSender.framework/MediaControlSender
0x372c3000 - 0x372f0ff3  MobileAsset armv7  <3a9e6258ae1230f5b12f1638b09cb974> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileAsset.framework/MobileAsset
0x37335000 - 0x37338ffe  MobileInstallation armv7  <c63e4b1ae40635cd9c6a7de851c80d10> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x37339000 - 0x3733fffd  MobileKeyBag armv7  <35882c57076334aeb0641969a9b69ff3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x3739c000 - 0x3739ffff  MobileSystemServices armv7  <10b4eee2739c353183ac2cfe4e39a443> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSystemServices.framework/MobileSystemServices
0x373b7000 - 0x373c0ffd  MobileWiFi armv7  <bb4efbe3c7273c0fb534f12789756089> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x37c8c000 - 0x37cb1ff9  OpenCL armv7  <9baf655cae4e3f9f99a5c6a99207099d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x38012000 - 0x3802ffff  PersistentConnection armv7  <c773b3dc885832f8a916de67f24f9f92> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x382c5000 - 0x382edfff  PrintKit armv7  <3f0b9c58a458358eb506858e8ff9e1fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x382ee000 - 0x38362ff7  ProofReader armv7  <9cb25467554637bcb268ba30527d3c0f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x38363000 - 0x3836bfff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <d1f2888d5e5a39cca6a6179a35c86770> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x384a7000 - 0x384b8ff8  SpringBoardServices armv7  <0e48e91ad40f34aab3323c7c4157ce52> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x3851a000 - 0x385f5fff  StoreServices armv7  <6d45f42eff2736d18cdd81af0473dd5a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x38643000 - 0x38645fff  TCC armv7  <d5bef30a5bda315194173b862975f9fb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC
0x38664000 - 0x38671ffb  TelephonyUtilities armv7  <803d7a92439238ee942086999c481eb6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TelephonyUtilities.framework/TelephonyUtilities
0x38af4000 - 0x38b94fff  UIFoundation armv7  <9a464526e26634bc834537e5ac3abf1f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/UIFoundation
0x38e98000 - 0x38eb7ffd  WebBookmarks armv7  <77b65bc9c87b367ebea9a5b7984b13a5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x38eb8000 - 0x397e7ff1  WebCore armv7  <06c849df1ad435aeb8b6130d85cee5df> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x397e8000 - 0x398c5ff9  WebKit armv7  <e0768dbdbdf13c769af7959497e24024> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x39970000 - 0x39977ffe  XPCObjects armv7  <723fe314ab95381cbfa69a0000005692> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XPCObjects.framework/XPCObjects
0x3a6a5000 - 0x3a6abffc  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <f40705b5e9c43ce3b1f185fe690b9ac8> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x3a6ac000 - 0x3a6c2fff  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  <5a8a3d18a1ff3c97bd773705fef2d81c> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x3a6da000 - 0x3a6e6fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <d0dce72a604b37309b8714fb35d74468> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x3a6f8000 - 0x3a6f8fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <7aeeab280f7e361e9986d962d0fa5281> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x3a81a000 - 0x3a826fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <3870b1c8b1783b788bd51da1a04eae6e> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x3a827000 - 0x3a830fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <b04d27fa0f2d31d8bd0745f8aa0d7f67> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x3a831000 - 0x3a87bff0  libc++.1.dylib armv7  <ceb9fb64fb203d3a94063a9db6590ca4> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x3a87c000 - 0x3a88ffff  libc++abi.dylib armv7  <4b8520bc534231ae97ce146e076bc7bf> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x3a8c0000 - 0x3a9adff2  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <ac23bb84e91e35418c9a2fb4792658b2> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x3a9ae000 - 0x3aaf7ff7  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <da9d04cc6f6d3825aa52636342ef1e04> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x3aaff000 - 0x3aaffffd  liblangid.dylib armv7  <a10d8f96815d35e0a1d2c7b998a941f3> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x3ab02000 - 0x3ab09ffb  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <224c65d491603e21a78a00af9e10f012> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x3adea000 - 0x3adfffff  libmis.dylib armv7  <7502589f14733beb963c542fa40438c8> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x3ae28000 - 0x3af26b77  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <79e5d714945834e4b2587abfc6c7269c> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x3afea000 - 0x3affffff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <3ee61a04a99b322e97e179bc03c46cf1> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x3b024000 - 0x3b0a9ff9  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <cbefd01867b93d2a869a534825a1414c> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x3b0aa000 - 0x3b0f5fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <e3154b06ac5d360c948111abfb2bc339> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x3b0f6000 - 0x3b11cfff  libtidy.A.dylib armv7  <c43990ee3a5e389aacf288c3615a50dc> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x3b120000 - 0x3b1cdff7  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <28dcf6ee713b387ebb763d11d4b3cd37> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x3b1ce000 - 0x3b1eefff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7  <d327d9e0f43333568abda8d83558c8a9> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x3b1ef000 - 0x3b1fbfff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <3ea49513bc023326be68e35324c11d0e> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x3b1fc000 - 0x3b1ffffa  libcache.dylib armv7  <91862e82d5063531b4fb4da9a19e5365> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x3b200000 - 0x3b206fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7  <d9e66574881739e8b25c3ae087a9f409> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x3b207000 - 0x3b209ffc  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7  <6ac449c92d743640a23d9d1ebe0b48a9> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x3b20a000 - 0x3b20ffff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <87bcae8743ab35c8a070ac95b7d57acb> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x3b210000 - 0x3b245ff3  libcorecrypto.dylib armv7  <04b464137fc2304b84eeed1a5418f4a8> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x3b246000 - 0x3b263ff9  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <9323bb560d4e3a3fb41efdc78bd0cf94> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x3b264000 - 0x3b265fff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <c25502085c833181b2a12cf525cffde6> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x3b266000 - 0x3b267fff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <f0b2fad1b720361297e22866c5c0fb64> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x3b268000 - 0x3b268fff  libkeymgr.dylib armv7  <e19c865e73e2352bbc8022033e953f22> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x3b269000 - 0x3b26efff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <c8bedc36bc3d3b55b91b12ebb1240968> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x3b26f000 - 0x3b272ffe  libmacho.dylib armv7  <965ab939e24935e7a3a65981574a7745> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x3b273000 - 0x3b274fff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <295706037a5238b4aa145df7b9354a0e> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x3b275000 - 0x3b275fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <50a01a02f573317fbd21e1070b0afc7d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x3b276000 - 0x3b2fcff4  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <cacc68d271e53338b7780c26f651b767> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x3b2fd000 - 0x3b303ffe  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <6c5ac17133a1366aaeea5dc38dceaf1f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x3b304000 - 0x3b31cff7  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <5a4a4c9da868317db7f17cb616eb32d1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x3b31d000 - 0x3b333ffd  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <7d409890411a396a9c812f488f8ea99a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x3b334000 - 0x3b350fff  libsystem_m.dylib armv7  <036ea0321da038e8b69a0c4413da00fe> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x3b351000 - 0x3b35fffd  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <afc167a2e9be3dd6851da8deaf42bafd> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x3b360000 - 0x3b367fff  libsystem_notify.dylib armv7  <c1d71aa978383c51a9ba2b32782d6cc6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x3b368000 - 0x3b369ffc  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <45bb99d46408351a9c61b5326032adea> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x3b36a000 - 0x3b36afff  libunwind.dylib armv7  <df8f1d90cbb837cc92d5901fab94e6ca> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x3b36b000 - 0x3b380ff9  libxpc.dylib armv7  <7f983066ea4c3c119f3e2344a04fef6e> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
stem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <6c5ac17133a1366aaeea5dc38dceaf1f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x3b304000 - 0x3b31cff7  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <5a4a4c9da868317db7f17cb616eb32d1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x3b31d000 - 0x3b333ffd  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <7d409890411a396a9c812f488f8ea99a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x3b334000 - 0x3b350fff  libsystem_m.dylib armv7  <036ea0321da038e8b69a0c4413da00fe> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x3b351000 - 0x3b35fffd  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <afc167a2e9be3dd6851da8deaf42bafd> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x3b360000 - 0x3b367fff  libsystem_notify.dylib armv7  <c1d71aa978383c51a9ba2b32782d6cc6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x3b368000 - 0x3b369ffc  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <45bb99d46408351a9c61b5326032adea> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x3b36a000 - 0x3b36afff  libunwind.dylib armv7  <df8f1d90cbb837cc92d5901fab94e6ca> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x3b36b000 - 0x3b380ff9  libxpc.dylib armv7  <7f983066ea4c3c119f3e2344a04fef6e> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
</string>
    <key>displayName</key>
    <string>MobileVision</string>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>MobileVision</string>
    <key>os_version</key>
    <string>iPhone OS 6.1.3 (10B329)</string>
    <key>system_ID</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>version</key>
    <string>??? (???)</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Did you try to reproduce the error over Wifi or on cellular network? Because even i faced a strange issue some time back when my app was running on iPod and crashing on iPhone it turned out to be an issue of Addressbook Corefoundation string. I will suggest you to enable NSZombies from project Scheme

Comment: Make sure that your iPhone is running iOS 6.1.4 and then try again, it is hard to tell from what you posted what the problem could be.  All I can tell is that it is crashing while loading the storyboard or perhaps after.  Maybe your storyboard has a different name than the one that is being loaded?  Check that the filename of the storyboard matches the name of the storyboard that is set as the initial storyboard.

Comment: Thanks both for your answers. I enable NSZombies and app log this: "ASYNCSOCKET Exception: *** -[NSConcreteMutableData subdataWithRange:]: range {0, 4294967294} exceeds data length 4224". Apple how detect this? this is the problem?

Comment: Were you ever able to figure what the issue was ? I am facing the same issue on 6.1.4 but i can't recreate it on any other iOS

Comment: see my answer at bottom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, the problem was the storyboard.

1.- The error i reproduced with this procedure on device: [Technical Q&A QA1764](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1764/)
with this the app crashes immediately at launch, and a error message printed to the console (look in organizer)

2.- When you localized the storyboard with one language (spanish in my case), main .storyboard file was missing in archive. It's seems this is a error of xcode.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try running you app using instruments like zombies or allocations or even leaks. Check it in allocations or simply open activity monitor and check memory usage of your app. Maybe it uses a lot of memory and hence the warning.

Comment: Thanks prince for your answer.

When apple indicates the app crashes if for possible memory leaks? they different try the app?

I try instruments and see the memory grows up eternally but never crash the app.

consider this an app to view ip cameras and i use this mjpeg client : https://github.com/horsson/mjpeg-iphone

Thanks again